# Their likes Vs. their ilk

Tags: etymology, grammatical-number

E.g:

I can't trust the **likes** of these politicians.

I can't trust these politicians and their **ilk**.

Why is it incorrect to say *like instead of likes  or *ilks instead of ilk?

Also, does **like** derive from **ilk**?

Answer (score 1):

'Like' and 'ilk' have [separate](https://www.google.com/search?q=like%20etymology) [etymologies](https://www.google.com/search?q=ilk%20etymology).

'Like' derives from Old Norse (*líkr*) while 'ilk' comes from Old English (*ilca*). Both are related to 'alike,' however.

'The likes of' as a phrase has a meaning of 'those similar to.' *Those* being plural, 'likes' is also plural. 'The like of' in the singular is unidiomatic, and would have a meaning of 'the one similar to.'

'Their ilk' means 'their cast/class/type.' Excluding the rare case of specifically identifying two or more independent groups that you wish to refer to jointly as 'ilks' (and still it's an unidiomatic stretch), you won't find any use for the plural.